# Node & Passport : stay on the same page after login

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

With Passport and Express, I succeed handling user session. Because I have some pages, that do not need be logged to be viewed, a user can login in many page.

How should I handle passport.authenticate to redirect on the current page, augmented with user data.

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
);
```

Maybe a custom callback with a `res.send(req.user)`. As I'm completely not familiar, i just advises on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The user info will be put on the `req.user` "by passport"

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : 'back', // redirect back to the previous page
        failureRedirect : 'back', // redirect back to the previous page
        failureFlash : true
    })
);
```

The keyword `back`redirect to previous page.